# Adding fix button to all images in the slider - Materialize design

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am developing a simple website in [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) and using full page slider on the front page of my app. Now my slider has multiple images. I want to put a button and a div with some content in it on the slider and that need to common to all the images. One way of doing that is to put same button and div in all the images in slider but that would be too idiotic, so i wanted to put a button and div common to all the pages.

```
<div class="slider fullscreen "> 
   <ul class="slides"> 
     <li> <img src="abcd.jpg"> <!-- random image --> 
        <div class="caption left-align"> 
          <h3>XXXX</h3> 
            <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">YYYYY</h5> 
              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Click to login further</a>
         </div> 
     </li>  
   <li> <img src="efgh.jpg"> <!-- random image --> 
        <div class="caption right-align"> 
          <h3>XXXX</h3> 
            <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">DDD</h5> 
              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Click to login further</a>
         </div> 
     </li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Also i don't have any clue on how to add a `div` over the slider which will be common to all the images in the slider. I have tried putting below code inside slider, but it didn't worked.

```
<div class = "col s6-mine teal lighten-3 z-depth-3">
   <center><p>Material <br> Its a material design test page</p></center>
</div>
<div class = "col s6-mine teal lighten-3 z-depth-3">
   <center><p>Test<br> Trying putting div</p></center>
</div>
```

I will really appreciate any help or any guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Javascript, Jquery or a server side language will be needed. However if it is the same button for all, you could set it at an absolute position so it sits on top on the image.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - I can use python (server side language i am using), but can you give me a small context on how server side language can be used? Also, i will give a try to add absolute position in CSS for button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.slider').slider({
        full_width: true
      });
    });
```

```css
.buttons-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100vh);
  margin-top: 64px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 997;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.buttons-wrapper a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.mg-rg {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider fullscreen ">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.theatercomplex.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/theater-logo-theatercomplexnl.png">
      <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption left-align">
        <h3>XXXX</h3> 
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">YYYYY</h5> 
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.directdutch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/table-restaurant.jpg">
      <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption right-align">
        <h3>XXXX</h3> 
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">DDD</h5> 
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
  <div class="row center">
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn hoverable mg-rg">Click to login further</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you're looking for. if not i may not understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This is close enough, given the lack of clarity.

Comment: @Stannio : Yes this is exactly what i was looking for. I tried the idiot way of getting the same result. I put a same button in every part of slider. But this resolved my problem. I think, the same technique can be applied for getting the div also.